# Error: This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel, oxyplot

I have two tabs that is bind to one `viewmodel` which contain a `PlotModel` of `oxyplot` and view model selected through a `DataTemplate`.
When click on the first tab the `viewmodel` was bind properly but when switch to second tab above exception defined in title throw.
All of control is same in two tab.
Is it possible bind one object to two controls?

Comment: Post relevant code here. It's difficult to answer without seeing your code.

Answer (score 8):

I know what problem you are facing, as I had faced it myself. Oxyplot does not let you bind one model to two plots.

The reason: Once you assign a PlotModel to a Plotview, it becomes encapsulated in that PlotView object.

The only way you can solve the problem is to create separate PlotModel for each PlotView.